# install4j 7.0.11: installed application produces a missing DLL error when started

Tags: java, windows-7, java-9, install4j

I'm packaging my application with install4j 7.0.11 (bundled Java 9 and installed on Win7 64-bit). For some reason, when the installed application is starting, I get the following system error:

"The program can't start because api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer".

When the error message is dismissed, the application still loads. The initial startup from the installer works fine, but all subsequent launches from the start menu produce the error.

Strangely enough, the evaluation version generated an installer without this issue. Not sure what could have changed.

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Sasha

EDIT: Another Win7 machine didn't have this issue, but it's still a problem because there is no way of telling which user will get this error. Besides, since the last major version didn't produce this issue, it would be good to know if there is a fix.

ANOTHER EDIT: This [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/missing-api-ms-win-core-timezone-i1-1-0dll/3754703c-241c-451a-a9b6-e690399fc83e) suggests that the error may be caused by an unsatisfied dependency in the installer (a C++ redistributable). Some target computers may already have it, so they don't complain, but other do not. This is just a theory, so I'm hoping to hear from the developers.

FINAL EDIT: I compared installed VC++ redistributables on the two systems and installed the missing Visual C++ Redistributable 2013 on the machine with errors. Sure enough, it fixed the problem.

This is just a diagnosis and now it becomes a question for the developers of install4j: how do we avoid having to do this in the future? In a heterogeneous production environment, it would be difficult and a bit embarrassing to have to walk from computer to computer and install missing prerequisites. Especially since this wasn't necessary with previous versions.